# JAVA pass a method from outside class to the ThreadPool.submit()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I don't have previous experience with JAVA's concurrency, but ever done the same in C#.

**My task** 
To create a "worker" class for easy multi-threading (creating continuous threads) managing in my applications.
what i want to have as result(usage example):

```
Worker worker = new Worker();
worker.threadCount = 10;
worker.doWork(myMethod);
worker.Stop();
```

to be able to use it in any class in my app, accepting 'void' methods as 'worker.doWork(myMethod);' argument.

What did i done from my researches on question:

**class Worker**

```
package commons.Threading;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Worker {
    static Boolean IsRunning = true;
    public static int threadCount = 2;
    static ExecutorService threadPool = new ErrorReportingThreadPoolExecutor(threadCount);

    public void doWork(**argument method**) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        while (IsRunning) {
            threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
                      **argument method**
            });

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }


    public static void Stop(){
        IsRunning = false;
        threadPool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
        try {
            // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
            if (!threadPool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                threadPool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
                // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
                if (!threadPool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                    System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
            threadPool.shutdownNow();
            // Preserve interrupt status
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

**ErrorReportingThreadPoolExecutor**

```
package commons.Threading;

import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ErrorReportingThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    public ErrorReportingThreadPoolExecutor(int nThreads) {
        super(nThreads, nThreads,
                0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable task, Throwable thrown) {
        super.afterExecute(task, thrown);

        if (thrown != null) {
            // an unexpected exception happened inside ThreadPoolExecutor
            thrown.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (task instanceof Future<?>) {
            // try getting result
            // if an exception happened in the job, it'll be thrown here
            try {
                Object result = ((Future<?>)task).get();
            } catch (CancellationException e) {
                // the job get canceled (may happen at any state)
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // some uncaught exception happened during execution
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // current thread is interrupted
                // ignore, just re-throw
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // replace
        // ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        // with
        ExecutorService threadPool = new ErrorReportingThreadPoolExecutor(2);

        while (true) {
            threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Job is running...");

                    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                        int q = 1 / 0;
                    }

                    System.out.println("Job finished.");
                }
            });

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

So, the question is - how do i pass 'void' method from outside class here threadPool.submit(new Runnable() { *here* });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the Runnable itself is a parameter,

```
public void doWork(Runnable runnable) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    while (IsRunning) {
        threadPool.submit(runnable);

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Runnable is a `functional interface`,it has a single method **run** that takes no-param and returns `void`, and hence you can use it as a function.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){

  public void run(){
   // do work
  }
};
doWork(runnable);
```

You can express it more concisely if you are on Java 1.8

```
Runnable runnable = ()->{/**do work*/};
doWork(runnable);
```

Comment: so, if i need to pass a void there - i can do like this ? `worker.doWork(new Runnable() { myVoid();  });`